# Какой эмулятор мне подойдёт?

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня старый ноут при выборе современных эмуляторов сталкиваюсь с проблемой поддержки VT-x хотя в биосе у меня включена поддержка ускорения, но я так понимаю что мой интеловский процессор не поддерживает VT-x. Подскажите какой эмулятор в моём случае подойдёт мне для запуска приложений с помощью android studio?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала приложите конфиг вашего ПК, потому что пока сложно от чего-то отталкиваться не имея достаточно контекста проблемы

Comment: А OS какая? а то ответы для винды и убунты немного разные

Comment: @ S.H OS Windows

Comment: @Andrew https://ibb.co/m0Rwmg1

Comment: я думаю, вам лучше использовать не эмулятор, а реальное устройство по кабелю. С 3Гб оперативной памяти будет очень туго

Comment: @Эникейщик Я использую реальное устройство но нужен эмулятор

Comment: Да, наверное, мои советы в этом вопросе бесполезны. Удаляю свой ответ.